# Oracle Weblogic: Application never RUNNING, always STARTING in and no errors in logs

Tags: spring-boot, weblogic, war, weblogic12c

After adding the war to the Weblogic 12 console, we always see STARTING status in server, and when checking the server logs we see no errors. The status of the war in console is NEW, not even deployed or failed.

[weblogic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnSrT.png)

[server.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiuFe.png)

[server.out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CKO0.png)

We do not know what Weblogic files or options to check or what to do to see what is happening.

We have checked the log an .out files and there is no errors.